# How to create form controlling section?

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a form amd I am splitting the form to sections. I created a step form structure. User should move step by step in this structure.

I want to create another section where user can check user's answers before submitting the form. But I do not know how can I get and display the answers without saving form.

How can I do it?

**template**

```
<form id="msform" method="POST">
   {% csrf_token %}
    ....
   <fieldset>
      <h3>D Section</h3>
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-2"></div>
         <div class="col-8">
            {{ form.answer1|as_crispy_field }}
            {{ form.answer2|as_crispy_field }}
            {{ form.answer3|as_crispy_field }}
         </div>
         <div class="col-2"></div>
      </div>
      <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous btn btn-outline-dark" value="Geri" />
      <input type="button" name="make_payment" class="next btn btn-outline-primary" value="Kontrol" />
   </fieldset>
   ....
   <fieldset>
      <h1>CONTROL SECTION</h1>
      <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous btn btn-outline-dark" value="Previous" />
      <input type="button" name="make_payment" class="next btn btn-outline-primary" value="Gönder" />
   </fieldset>
</form>
```

To be clear:
[image: There is an image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either show all the answers using javascript before sending the form (by using one final section) or you can create a control page that handles the form and shows the answers. In this page you can pass the form answers as readonly input variables. Finally, after posting the page, you can handle the form in a third page (or you can use same page for these two post requests but send a hidden variable for deciding to show or save).